# How to retain column order using listagg in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake table A as below:

```
CREATE or replace table TABLEA
(
    Address VARCHAR(50),
    Zip VARCHAR(50),
    HASH VARCHAR(50));

insert into TABLEA (Address, Zip, HASH) values
    ('ABC', '20987', 'XX'),
    ('XYZ', '20989', 'XY'),
    ('CBZ', '20980', 'XZ');
```

I want to get all the column names from information schema as a string seperated by comma
exactly like the below query outputs

```
select listagg(COLUMN_NAME, ',') from db.information_schema.columns 
              where table_schema = 'schema' and TABLE_NAME = 'TABLEA'
```

but the problem with the above query is it doesnot retain the column order meaning when I execute the query 1st time, it outputs

```
ZIP,HASH,ADDRESS
```

whereas if I execute the same query again, it outputs

```
ADDRESS,ZIP,HASH
```

The column order is not the same, I want the column order to be consistent (as in the table) every time the query is executed

### UPDATE

Adding order by ORDINAL_POSITION worked

```
select listagg(COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION) from db.information_schema.columns 
                  where table_schema = 'schema' and TABLE_NAME = 'TABLEA'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION